# Disabled a button when input filed is empty without using a handler

Tags: reactjs, button

I tried to disabled a button when input filed is empty without using a handler.
Before I check the condition, I only want to simply enabled the button when input is changed (not yet check if content of input) but I did see the state is changed (I can see it in the alert) but the button is never enabled (I can see that in debugger)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {'enableAdd':false}

}

Text: <input id="textInput" type="text" onChange={()=>{this.state.enableAdd=true;alert(this.state.enableAdd)}}/>
<button onClick={this.addTODO} disabled={!this.state.enableAdd} style={{"paddingLeft":"7px"}}>Add</button>
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check, **how to update state value?**

Instead of changing the state value directly `this.state.enableAdd = true;` use `setState`.

Like this:

```
this.setState({enableAdd=true});
```

Check the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) how to use `state` in `React` and for other details.

Check the working example of your problem:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {'enableAdd':false};
       this.addTODO = this.addTODO.bind(this);
    }
    
    addTODO(){
       console.log('clicked');
    }
  
    render(){
        return  <div>
           <input id="textInput" type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({enableAdd: e.target.value != ''})}/>
           <button onClick={this.addTODO} disabled={!this.state.enableAdd}>Add</button>
       </div>
    }   
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```